# Jquery Mobile listview search

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview, jquery-mobile-dialog

I am creating a project whereby the user enter a name and the name pops up in the box but you can click to get more information in a dialog box.  My code is working but for the dialog to show the full information correctly you need to type at least 4 characters in the search field.  I would like user to be able to get additional information even if they enter less than 4 characters.  See below :)

[search screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmYDC.png)

[dialog screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzShB.png)

Below is my script, I hope this makes sense to someone.  :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#search').click(function() {
        $(".artist").remove();  // removes the artist class to clear search
        var artists = "js/data.json"; // places the file link into variable

        $.getJSON( artists, function(data) { //  uses the variable to connect to json file
            console.log(data);  
            $.each( data, function( i, item ) { // loops through the json files to retrieve required info
            // section for artists brief intro 
            $("ul#artist").append( "<li class='artist'><span style='font-size:24px; font-weight:bold;color:red;'>"  + item.name  + 
                "</span><br/>" + item.reknown + 
                "<br/><button class='ui-btn' id='information'><a href='#dialog' data-role='button' id='dialog' data-transition='flip'>More Information</a></button></li>");
            }); // end of each function

            $('#search').first().one('keyup', function(){   
             $.each( data, function( i, item ) {    // loops through the json files to retrieve required info
            // section for artists dialog full profile data
            $("ul#artist2").append( "<li class='artist'><span style='font-size:24px; font-weight:bold;color:red;'>" + item.name + 
                "</span><br/> " + item.reknown + 
                "<br/><img class='profile' src='images/" + item.shortname + "_tn.jpg' />" + 
                "<br/><span style='font-size:18px; color:red; font-weight:bold'>Bio:</span><br> " + item.bio + "</li>"); 

                });  // end of information function
             }); // end of each function  
        }); // end of getJson function 
    });  // end of submit on click function

});  // end document ready function
```

Comment: Can you create a simple jsFiddle with some local JSON to demonstrate the issue? Also, what version of jQM are you using? popup might be better than dialog.

Comment: Hi thank you for replying to me.  I haven't used jsFiddler but have put my work up on codepen.io if that helps.  http://codepen.io/Jacqueline34/pen/JXzqVv  as you will see the json file I have put at the bottom of the script file as I didn't know where to copy it too (I had it as a local external file).  I don't have images loaded either but I don't think this would be a problem.  :)

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yLpjs856/

Comment: Perfect!  just like that.  Thank you for the lesson ezanker :)